# How to combine the Profit and Loss in a table in the same group in excel?

Tags: excel, grouping

[image]

Hi all,

I want to combine the profit and loss in this table based on the groups. So the final P/L after grouping for Group A will be 8, Group B = 2, Group C = 6 and Group D = 13. I know pivot table able to achieve this easily but I don't want to use pivot table as sometimes it might cause a lot of problems. Is there any other method or function that I can use to group them assumeing that there will be other group (e.g. Group E, Group F,...) and the number of rows will increase in the future. Thank you!

Comment: I would use sumifs().

Comment: But the problems for `sumifs` is that there are more groups in the future and I don't know whether it will be extended to Group F or even Group Z. `Sumifs` only works if the group already exits.

Comment: then create the unique values by using the method i mention in my answer.

Comment: What kind of problems are you worried about with a Pivot Table?  It is certainly the simplest of the various solutions, and will update/group automatically when you Refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use sumifs() like so:

[image]

All you need is a list of unique values and you can do that by copying column A, pasting it in another column and then using Remove duplicates.

This is the formula used so you can copy and paste:

```
SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D2)
```

Edit: Based on Pb's comment using unique(), entered as an array formula new groups appear while the first non-found is 0. Then the sumifs can be dragged down and if() could be used to deal with 0 depending on what other calculations there are.

Comment: I tried the method just now, but it seems like need to create column D manually. If there are two rows of new data (belong to Group E, with P/L -5 and -4), then the Group of new data in column A will not reflect on column D and hence column E will not have the sum of Group E which is -9 right?

Comment: @Elvis 1) this is a new problem 2) add the fresh data to cols A & b then add the new group to col D either manually or the method I stated.

Comment: If you use office 365 you can get your list of unique values in column D by using `=UNIQUE(A:A)` and combine it with the solution given above.

Comment: So actually both are considered manual work right. Adding new data to column A & B will not automatically group them together and appear in column D and E